# EF 6 Caching withing a context

Tags: entity-framework

I have a single DbContext.. First I do:

```
var all = context.MySet.Where(c=>c.X == 1).ToList();
```

later (with the same context instance)

```
var special = context.MySet.Where(c=>(c.X == 1) && (c.Y===1).ToList();
```

The database is hit AGAIN!  Since the first query is guaranteed
 to return all of the elements that will exist in the second, why is the DB being hit again?

Comment: *the first query is guaranteed to return all of the elements that will exist in the second* Unless in the mean time records have been inserted/updated/deleted. If you want to access the cache, query the `Local` collection: `context.MySet.Local`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to avoid hitting the database again then you could try this;

```
var special = all.Where(c=>(c.X == 1) && (c.Y===1).ToList();
```

Since the list of all objects already contains everything you want you can just query that list and the database won't get hit again.

Your link expression is just a query, it only retrieves data when you enumerate it (for example calling .ToList()). You can keep changing the query and hold off actually getting the data until you need it. The entity framework will convert your query into an SQL query in the background and then fetch data.

Avoid writing "ToList()" at the end of every query as this forces the EF to hit the database.

If you only ever what to hit the database once then get the data you need by calling "ToList(), To.Array etc and then work with that collection (in your case the "all" collection) since this is the object holding all the data.